# Lightweight javascript real-time ticker

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using ajax to pull from a php file that pulls from a database that gets updated (truncate/insert) every minute. I call the ajax with a setInterval() every 30 seconds. After about 50 people got on the site, it crashed. Is there a better way to set it up to handle more users?

Comment: describe 'it crashed' ...

Comment: It started giving forbidden errors, and taking super long to load a page

Comment: I just now realized you're running truncate and then insert. What's the reason for running truncate? What you have got going on is people trying to access the database in the middle of a truncate operation, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly, the reason for the truncate is I only need the most current data(it comes into the site from a post every minute ~500 rows)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try using a cron job to run a single query every 30 seconds, storing the result in a global variable `$GLOBALS['results'];` and then letting your users pull that back to their browser instead of letting each user hit the database.

And depending on what your're storing (totals perhaps) you could optimize the query by only pulling the records created since the last update.

Comment: 1) cron does not go below 1 minute. 2) `$GLOBALS` is bad. 3) the context of the cron job (_that_ `$GLOBALS`) would still not be available to the other pages because... PHP life cycle and shared memory. The result would need to be persisted in another way (perhaps in the db)

Comment: He's trying to avoid hitting the database for each user. My approach is not wrong, you just don't like it.

Two cron jobs running a minute apart would do the same thing. My answer still isn't wrong.

Comment: the _approach_ itself isn't bad. It's the details. To be fair, with a bit of skill, a script _can_ be executed every 30s (but not _just_ with cron). Also, leaving aside my dislike for `$GLOBALS`, you still can't directly pass results from a cronjob to a webscript. There's no connection between the two. No shared context/memory. So that result _must_ be "written" down somewhere (a file, a table, etc)